# EWS: FindItem returns ErrorNonExistentMailbox for Contacts folder

Tags: exchangewebservices

Our application uses EWS to backup Exchange mailboxes (including Office 365 mailboxes).
The application uses OAth2 authentication and requires an account with Exchange administrator role to authenticate. The application gets a list of mailboxes and gets a full access for the admin account to a particular mailbox using cmdlets of Exchange Online Management module.

It worked fine for years until FindItem started to return ErrorNonExistentMailbox for Contacts folder.
FindFolder returns "success" for the same folder. There are no problems for any other folders (including Calendar, Tasks and so on)

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="4" Time="2023-08-28 12:40:51Z" Version="0.0.0.0">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:FindFolder Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:FolderShape>
          <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
          <t:AdditionalProperties>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:DisplayName" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:ChildFolderCount" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:TotalCount" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:FolderClass" />
          </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:FolderShape>
        <m:IndexedPageFolderView MaxEntriesReturned="300" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
        <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="contacts">
            <t:Mailbox>
              <t:EmailAddress>alex@ra*.com</t:EmailAddress>
            </t:Mailbox>
          </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
        </m:ParentFolderIds>
      </m:FindFolder>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
<Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="4" Time="2023-08-28 12:40:53Z" Version="0.0.0.0">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="6699" MinorBuildNumber="34" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
      <m:FindFolderResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:FindFolderResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
            <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:RootFolder IndexedPagingOffset="8" TotalItemsInView="8" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
              <t:Folders>
                <t:ContactsFolder>
                  <t:FolderId Id="AAMkADdhNGNjMjZjLTc1NTEtNDA5ZS05NWE4LWQ..." ChangeKey="AwAAABYAAAB6owpFxfBvQLC3vHbnrlnCAAD0fR4P" />
                  <t:FolderClass>IPF.Contact.OrganizationalContacts</t:FolderClass>
                  <t:DisplayName>Organizational Contacts1</t:DisplayName>
                  <t:TotalCount>0</t:TotalCount>
                  <t:ChildFolderCount>0</t:ChildFolderCount>
                </t:ContactsFolder>
              </t:Folders>
            </m:RootFolder>
          </m:FindFolderResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:FindFolderResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</Trace>
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="4" Time="2023-08-28 12:40:54Z" Version="0.0.0.0">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
          <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
          <t:AdditionalProperties>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemClass" />
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="aaee6810-ec59-48f0-824d-bccaa610bbdb" PropertyId="1" PropertyType="String" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:LastModifiedTime" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Size" />
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="12299" PropertyType="Binary" />
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="26082" PropertyType="Binary" />
          </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:ItemShape>
        <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="1000" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
        <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="contacts">
            <t:Mailbox>
              <t:EmailAddress>alex@ra*.com</t:EmailAddress>
            </t:Mailbox>
          </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
        </m:ParentFolderIds>
      </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
<Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="4" Time="2023-08-28 12:40:55Z" Version="0.0.0.0">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="6699" MinorBuildNumber="34" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
      <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
            <m:MessageText>Mailbox does not exist.</m:MessageText>
            <m:ResponseCode>ErrorNonExistentMailbox</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:FindItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

**Update:** The same error happens for GetItem operation for contact items if they are non-Contacts folders (e.g. in Deleted Items)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the X-AnchorMailbox header ? If you try to do the same thing in the EWSeditor does it give the same error https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases. Can you reproduce the same error on multiple tenants ?

Comment: In fact, we use EWS Managed API Version: 2.2.1.0. It doesn't set X-AnchorMailbox for FindItem as well as for GetItem. I added X-AnchorMailbox header for these operations but the same error happened.  I found a reason.  We use and recommended to our clients to create a separate _unlicensed_ user with Exchange Administrator role to backup mailboxes. If a licensed user is used to authenticate, the contacts are downloaded successfully.